# get a resource uri from jsm

Tags: javascript, firefox, gecko, jsm

I'd like to get the `resource:` uri for a `.jsm` file dynamically.  The path is dynamic so I would like to refer to relative resources with the same path.

So I can load `A.jsm` via `resource://path-to-modules/modules/A.jsm` and `resource://path-to-modules/modules/B.jsm`, and I have `B.jsm` which `A.jsm` depends on.

So I want something like `Cu.import(path.replace("A.jsm", "B.jsm"))`

any idea how I would get `path` in the above?

Comment: Which path is it that you want?

Comment: The specific path that I want doesn't matter, just use the example path. `path-to-modules` (I updated the example)